# syntax of lambda functions in java 8

Tags: java, lambda, anonymous-function, java-8

I am new to java, and I do not know how to write a simple lambda function. I tried to read some articles, like [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html), but I do not manage to compile, as I get error of syntax.

I wish to replace the function `F` is in this code with a `λ-function`

```
class Test {
  private int N;
  public Test (int n) {
      N = n;
  }

  private int f (int x) {                   /* <== replace this */
      return 2*x;
  }

  public void print_f () {
      for (int i = 0; i < this.N; i++)
          System.out.println (f(i));        /* <== with lambda here*/
  }

  public static void main (String[] args) {
      int n = 10;
      if (args.length == 1)
          n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
      Test t = new Test (n);
      t.print_f ();
  }
}
```

**EDIT**: My question concerns ***only the syntax*** of *λ-functions* in Java. Not the syntax of anonymous classes.

Comment: Java 8? Other versions do not support lambdas.

Comment: java -version `=>` java version "1.8.0-ea"

Comment: And i thought my eyes betray me, "lambdas", "java"?

Comment: In which case you need to read about [Lambda Expressions in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html). You cannot simply pass a function - you need to create a [SMI](http://java.dzone.com/articles/introduction-functional-1)

Comment: Should I install other development version of java ? It works with this one ?

Comment: Can you simply re-write my code, for it to compile, and have a concrete example, please ?

Comment: Boris, my java version is good for this ? Should I install a latter one ?

Comment: Yes, your version looks good.

Comment: I tried to insert the lambda function, ans whatever I tried, I get the syntax error ``error: illegal start of expression`` in the place where I insert the `->`, like in `x->2*x`.

Comment: In the article you quote, they talk about anonymous classes , not about anonymous functions. I am not interested about anonymous classes, but only anonymous functions.

Comment: @BoristheSpider There are SMIs ready to use for such simple cases.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik of course, I just think the OP needs to _understand_ how lambda's work - there seems to be the impression that Java has acquired "anonymous functions".

Comment: @BoristheSpider I see your point, and OP's comment below my answer confirms this. However, Java *did* acquire anonymous functions; what it didn't acquire is a complete *lambda function type system*, where the type of the function does not piggyback on the old Java type system as SMIs, but is built into the language. Note that even in that case, you would still need to spell out the function type in the method signature; this could be avoided only by advanced type inference, which would infer the type of argument from its usage in the body.

Comment: I want to understand `ONLY THE SYNTAX` in java. I have been using lambdas in lisp and python for more than 10 years .

Comment: Java 8 syntax looks like Scala. It is stange that previous versions of Java did not have lambdas, as time as they had iterators. Because the iterators are implemented as a lambda function (thunks).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first recommendation would be to use NetBeans, which will teach you how to transform your code into lambdas in many cases. In your specific code you want to transform a `for (int i = 0;...)` kind of loop. In the lambda world, you must express this as a *list comprehension* and more specifically for Java, as a *stream transformation*. So the first step is to acquire a *stream of integers*:

```
IntStream.range(0, this.N)
```

and then apply a lambda function to each member:

```
IntStream.range(0, this.N).forEach(i->System.out.println(f(i)));
```

A complete method which replaces your `print_f` would look as follows:

```
public void print_f() {
    IntStream.range(0, this.N).forEach(i->System.out.println(f(i)));
}
```

However, in the world of lambdas it would be more natural to fashion `print_f` as a *higher-order function*:

```
public void print_f(IntConsumer action) {
    IntStream.range(0, this.N).forEach(action);
}
```

And now your complete program would look like this:

```
import java.util.function.IntConsumer;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

class Testing {
    private int N;
    public Testing (int n) {
        N = n;
    }

    private static int f (int x) {
        return 2*x;
    }

    public void print_f(IntConsumer action) {
        IntStream.range(0, this.N).forEach(action);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int n = 10;
        if (args.length == 1)
            n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        Testing t = new Testing (n);
        t.print_f(i->System.out.println(f(i)));
    }
}
```

... well, except that a `print_f` method should really do the printing and accept only the transformation function, which turns your code into the following:

```
public void print_f(IntFunction f) {
    IntStream.range(0, this.N).forEach(i->System.out.println(f.apply(i)));
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    int n = 10;
    if (args.length == 1)
        n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    Testing t = new Testing (n);
    t.print_f(Testing::f);
}
```

... or, eliminating the `f` method altogether,

```
t.print_f(i->2*i);
```

Comment: Okay... You used the predefined function type `java.util.function.IntFunction`. What would you have done if the function you needed had not had a predefined type ?

Comment: Trying to compile the first version of the complete program, I get compiling with`javac Test.java && java Test 202` many errors, the first one is:
Test.java:18: error: illegal start of expression
        IntStream.range(0, this.N).forEach(i->System.out.println(f.apply(i)));

Comment: I had a messed-up version of code at one point; try now. It compiles and runs for me, `build 1.8.0-ea-b108`. Be careful with older builds, the Streams API has changed.

Comment: If you are using `IntStream.forEach`, you can't run into the situation where the interface is not predefined because `forEach`, as well as any other stream-related JDK method, has a definite argument type, and that type by implication already exists.

Comment: You run into a situation where you don't have a predefined type only when you code your own library which supports the lambda syntax *at the client side*. At the library side, there is never a trace of the lambda syntax in method signatures.

Comment: Can you tell me step by step how to compile it, please ?

Comment: No special steps necessary. Just as you mentioned above, but making sure that you use JDK 8 javac. Note that good output from `java -version` is no proof that `javac` is also Java 8. Check with `javac -version`.

Comment: I am working in emacs and console :). No other environment for editing/compiling.

Comment: javac -version `==>` javac 1.7.0_21. I was not using java 8.

Comment: "What would you have done if the function you needed had not had a predefined type?" You can always define your own functional interface, and use a lambda where that functional interface is expected. The only requirement on the interface is that it have exactly one abstract method (but it can have default and static methods).

Comment: @StuartMarks And it can even be an abstract class, with many other methods already implemented. The shortcut SAM (Single Abstract Method) says it all...

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question , using the answer provided by Marko Topolnik, here is a complete file `Test.java`, which does exactly what I asked, using the principle Keep It Simple Stupid.

In this case, I generalized from the function **λ(int)->int** to **λ(int,int)->int**.

All possible type of functions that can be defined are found here:

http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html

```
import java.util.function.BiFunction;

class Test {
  public static void main (String[] args) {
      int n = 10;
      if (args.length == 1) n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
      for (int i=0; i <= n; i++)
          System.out.println (((BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer>)
                               (x,y)->2*x+y).apply(i,1));
  }
}
```

Many more examples can be found here:

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html?cid=7180&ssid=105274749521607

Comment: I wouldn't say that java.util.function defines "all possible types of functions." It certainly defines the most common ones. However, we expect that people will one across the need for others. You can simply define your own functional interfaces and use lambdas with them.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. If you wish, please edit my message, and tell how can we define the *most* general type -- but please keep it as simple as possible.